# How to call a Method to another Method in the same class

Tags: java, methods

I have a method called countDirectSimilarity, in this method I want to call another method, but I find it difficult to call it, can you help me?

here the source code, i will call method name countAggrIntStrength

```
private double countDirectSimilarity(double[][] matrixEgoNetwork, int index) {
    double sim=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixEgoNetwork.length; i++) {

//here the trouble 
        if (matrixEgoNetwork[i][0]==this.countAggrIntStrength(*here the error*) && matrixEgoNetwork[i][index]!=0) {
            sim++;

        }
    }

    return sim;

}
```

this is  method that I want to call

```
public double countAggrIntStrength(Map<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>> neighborsHist) {
    double AggrIntStrength = 0;
    double lambda = 0, sigma = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>> data : neighborsHist.entrySet()) {
        lambda = data.getValue().get(0);
        sigma = data.getValue().get(1);

        AggrIntStrength = this.countAgrIntStrength(lambda, sigma);
    }

    return AggrIntStrength;
}
```

another problem is that the data structure that I want to enter into 
    this.countAggrIntStrength() 
is in another class, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **static**

```
public static double countAggrIntStrength...
```

And in your method do not need this.countDirectSimilarity, you can just directly call countDirectSimilarity method.

Comment: thank you sir, you inspired me to change the attribute from another class. from protected to public static

Answer (score 0):

Get the data structure from the other class using a getter:

```
otherClassName.getMap()
```

Then pass it to your method within the first class, either within the method call:

```
countAggrIntStrength(otherClassName.getMap());
```

Or by saving it first:

```
Map<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>> mapToPass = otherClassName.getMap();
countAggrIntStrength(mapToPass)
```

You'll need a getter in the other class:

```
public Map getMap(){
    return variableThatStoresTheMap;
}
```

if you don't already have one.

Answer (score 0):

Some data Structure class which holds neighborsHist map.

```
public class DataStructure {

    Map<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>> neighborsHist;

    public Map<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>> getNeighborsHist() {
        return neighborsHist;
    }

    public void setNeighborsHist(Map<DTNHost, ArrayList<Double>> neighborsHist) {
        this.neighborsHist = neighborsHist;
    }

    public void businessLogicFunc() {
        //business logic function.
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside your countDirectSimilarity function call get method.

```
public DataStructure dataStructure;

private double countDirectSimilarity(double[][] matrixEgoNetwork, int index) {
    double sim=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < matrixEgoNetwork.length; i++) {

        if (matrixEgoNetwork[i][0]==this.countAggrIntStrength(dataStructure.getNeighborsHist()) && 
            matrixEgoNetwork[i][index]!=0) {
            sim++;

        }
    }

    return sim;

}
```